# How to get the current index of for loop with jijna2?

Tags: python, jinja2

Let's say that I have a code like:

```
{% for x in posts %}
   <p>We are in item: {{ x }}</>
{% else %}
```

And I want to get the current index of the for loop to run an if loop, something like(logically):

```
{% for x in posts %}
 {% if x.index = 0 %}
   <p>We are in the first item!</p>
 {% else %}
   <p>We are in item: {{ x }}</>
 {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

How to do it inside jijna2? (I use Python with Flask).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `loop.index` inside the loop.

```
{% for x in posts %}
    <p>We are in item number: {{ loop.index }}</>
{% else %}
```

[Flask Template docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use several loop related variables for that

http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#list-of-control-structures